# Compiled Node.Js app links to github, possible to redirect to different repository?

Tags: node.js, github

I have an app that I use that uses a repository on github. The app is compiled and I cannot edit it, is it possible to redirect the github request to another repository? Like to intercept the request? I am interested in making some changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hum... if you can't access to the source code it seems undoable.

But maybe a weebhook on your repository can do the job :

https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

Comment: Thanks i will look into this!